# Undesired white vertical bar on the right side of webpage

Tags: html, css, line

[image]I am having a problem with a vertical white bar on the right side appearing on my webpage I was creating. I tried looking up other solutions on StackOverflow. People mentioned having class="row" without a container is a problem sometimes, but I do not see this in my code. Also, they said margin could be an issue. I tried deleting and editing portions of my code with that, and nothing seemed to work.

I have isolated the problem being within the `<main>` tag. I tried deleting parts of the code at a time to see if deleting a part would fix it. No such luck so far.

If you could help me figure this out, I would greatly appreciate it. I've been trying to figure this out for the last hour or so.

It's on codepen. https://codepen.io/brendenbass/pen/qBrMdmb

Comment: By vertical white bar, do you mean the scrollbar or something else entirely? Because I'm not seeing it in the link you gave other than the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: @YongPin I do mean the scrollbar. Behind the scrollbar, there is a white bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the scrollbar but keep it's functionality:

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
html {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any white vertical bar in the code you provided. Can you put some screenshots? Otherwise, kindly check the code once again.

Comment: I added the picture so you can see. It's behind the scrollbar on the far right. @Amith helped me out. Thank you though.